# razor dropdown list add the data but show after refresh the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

```
@{
    HotelManagementEntities db = new HotelManagementEntities();
    var list = db.tblCategories.Select(m => new { m.intseqid, m.varCategory}).ToList();
    ViewBag.Category = new SelectList(db.tblCategories, "intseqid", "varCategory");

}

@Html.DropDownList("tblCategories", 
                   ViewBag.Category as SelectList, 
                   new 
                   { 
                     @class = "drplist", 
                     id = "drpItemCat", 
                     ng_show = "selectfieldforcat" 
                   })
```

Comment: why you put this code in cshtml file . you can easy move it to controller and and on controller constructor fill this viewbag and then see if it work

Answer (score 0):

There are problems in your code, you are populating list from database here:

```
var list = db.tblCategories.Select(m => new { m.intseqid, m.varCategory}).ToList();
```

but down in the code when creating `SelectList`, you are again getting records form the database using the dbContext:

```
ViewBag.Category = new SelectList(db.tblCategories, "intseqid", "varCategory");
// note the db.tblCategories as first parameter, this is wrong
```

and if you have actually written this code in view, then you don't even need `ViewBag`, but your approach is not right, you should be writing the poupulation code in the controller action and then use it in the view:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{

   HotelManagementEntities db = new HotelManagementEntities();

   ViewBag.Category = new SelectList(db.tblCategories, "intseqid", "varCategory");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact, it's not a good practice to have data retrieval in views, based on you code, you could try the following:

```
@{
    var db = new HotelManagementEntities();
    var list = db.tblCategories.Select(m => new 
    { 
        m.intseqid, 
        m.varCategory
    }).ToList();
}

@Html.DropDownList("tblCategories", new SelectList(@list, "intseqid", "varCategory"));
```

A more appropriate approach it would be to create a model, which would contain as a property a `SelectList` object. Then at the corresponding action at the controller to create a new model and set the categories to mentioned above property. Last pass at your view (so now you have to define that your view expects a model of a specific type, that you declared above) the model and at the dropdownlist html helper do the following:

```
@Html.DropDownList("tblCategories", Model.Categories)
```

This way you are more adhered to separation of concerns that is built in the MVC pattern and your code would be more readable and maintainable in the long run. Your example is pretty simple. So that I mentioned before cannot be seen at this point. However, while you model would be more complex and you have to do more things in the views, you will see that I mean by saying more readable and maintainable.

Last but not least, try to avoid using the ViewBag. Apparently you can accomplish what you have to do with the use of ViewBag, but it's far better you pass a strongly typed object as a model to your view and have there all you need to show on the view rather than adding things in the ViewBag at the controller and then use casts in the view to do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

In Controller:

```
public ActionResult Add()
            {
              ViewBag.countryList = GetCountries();
              return View();
            }
```

In razor View .csHtml

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.countryId, new SelectList(ViewBag.countryList, "id", "Name"), 'Select Country',
                                    new { @id = "ddlCountry", @rows = 1 })
```